# Node.js online app with intranet DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, intranet

What I want to build is an application that sits online and it's used by different groups that each have their own intranet. Now, because of a stupid security policy the data can't sit outside the intranet. How would you go about building an app that it's still online, so you can push updates to everyone at once, but has a DB on each intranet's server?
My initial plan is to use Node.js and MongoDB.

Comment: Any reason why each intranet should have a DB. Is it ok if the database is on any one intranet and accessible to the others via the internet.

Comment: It's because of a security policy, the entities are not allowed to store data outside their intranets. So each intranet needs his own local DB unfortunately.

Comment: Seems like the solution shouldn't be implemented like that. I would go for a change in the policy instead. Creating a solution to work around a policy is rarly a good way to do it.

Comment: A change in policy is impossible unfortunately in this case. I'm researching this approach as an alternative to deploying the application on each intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your db really has to be onsite, and your app really has to be offsite, then probably your only option is to set up a secure connection from your app, to the onsite db, and pretend as if its hosted locally to the app.   This may/may not violate the security policies.  You could in theory lock it down pretty well, with a vpn between the two networks.  But this is not for the faint of heart, performance will suffer, and it does have security issues.  It also means a bit of work for every site.

If the only reason you're wanting it to be "online" is for pushing updates as you stated, then you'll do better installing the app on-premise, and getting it to poll into a central server for notifications about new versions, download updates to itself, and install them automatically. Once you've created this, a new installation requires no new work.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!
If I go only the intranet "way", do you think using git would be a good idea for pulling updates from a central repo?

Comment: Could work, but any kind of technology that can poll in, download, and "install" (in your case perhaps just copy over) would do.  The only other thing you may want to consider is if there are any other tasks necessary during upgrades (e.g. connecting to mongo and running some upgrade scripts).  In which case you may want to work that logic into your app (i.e. check a flag at startup to see if you've done that work or not) or consider something more sophisticated (e.g. a standalone "agent" installed on the intranet that manages all this for you).  I'd start with the most simplest thing first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem right now, so here's my take on it, not really mongo or node specifc.

1. Put a db and a simple restful server on each of client's intranets. Servers can be exactly the same.
2. Put a routing facade accesible from internet that redirects requests to apropriate server based on url, ie: `http://facade/server/resource` becomes a request to `http://server/resouce`.
3. Configure the facade so that a requests to `http://facade/resource` go to each server, retrieve results and return all of them in some aggregated form.

Obviously there are more details to take into account, like permissions (can everybody publish to each server? if not, who can?), but the general idea is there.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something along the same lines. Permissions are not a problem on my side, as each intranet is independent from the others.